# Simple proof that an operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $\phi$ be a compactly supported smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm looking for a simple proof that the operator

$$\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2\right)^{-1}\phi$$
(where $x$ denotes multiplication by $x$) is a compact operator $H^1(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

**Added after:** Is it true that $\left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2\right)^{-1}$ is a bounded operator $L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^1(\mathbb{R})$? How to prove this?

**Remark:** I believe one can show this by some clever means, like using a special basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined using Hermite polynomials, but I'm looking for something more down-to-earth, coming straight out of functional analysis.

Comment: It's not a special basis. It is the orthonormal basis that diagonalizes $L=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2$. So it's built for the job.

Comment: What I would like is to solve the problem when $x^2$ is replaced by a function $f(x)$ satisfying some conditions, and I'm not sure if the argument using Hermite polynomials would generalize to this case.

Comment: If you replace $x^2$ by $0$ it's not compact. What type of function are you thinking about?

Comment: You can search on keywords "confining potential".

Comment: Let's consider the operator $D=-\frac{d}{dx}+f(x)$. I would like to show that $D$ is Fredholm when $f(x)$ is smooth and satisfies: $f(x)\rightarrow\pm\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ and $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks, I'm looking at your book now.

Comment: Barry Simon has written many things about (confining) potentials.

Comment: @ougoah One possible reference is Simon. *Schrödinger operators with purely discrete spectrum*,  Methods Funct. Anal. Topology 15 (2009). The operator $-\Delta+V$ has compact resolvent if $V\geq0 $ and all sublevel sets of $V$ have finite measure. In particular, this result holds when $V(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to\pm \infty$.

Comment: Hey @MaoWao, I don't quite understand what you're saying here, but it looks like it might be an answer. If so, can you write it as an Answer so that we can get this out of the unanswered queue?